# Basic, single-threaded implementation of SynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am trying to write a `SynchronizationContext` in C# that represents a message queue, to be pumped from a main loop.

*Edit*: I see that I have forgotten to say - I need the message loop executions to be done a single, pre-determined thread. (In my case I want to push updates to an OpenGL context.)

Here is the class I have written:

```
public class SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    private sealed class WorkItem
    {
        private readonly SendOrPostCallback _callback;
        private readonly object _state;
        private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _reset;

        public WorkItem (SendOrPostCallback callback, object state, ManualResetEventSlim reset)
        {
            if (callback == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("callback");

            _callback = callback;
            _state = state;
            _reset = reset;
        }

        public void Execute ()
        {
            _callback (_state);
            if (_reset != null) {
                _reset.Set (); 
            }
        }
    }

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem> _workItems = new ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem> ();
    private readonly Thread _executingThread;

    public SingleThreadedSynchronizationContext (Thread executingThread)
    {
        if (executingThread == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException ("executingThread");
        _executingThread = executingThread;
    }

    internal bool HasWorkItems {
        get {
            return !_workItems.IsEmpty;
        }
    }

    private WorkItem ExecuteAndReturnNextWorkItem ()
    {
        WorkItem currentItem;
        if (_workItems.TryDequeue (out currentItem)) {
            currentItem.Execute ();
        }
        return currentItem;
    }

    private void ExecuteNextWorkItem ()
    {
        ExecuteAndReturnNextWorkItem ();
    }

    public override void Post (SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        _workItems.Enqueue (new WorkItem (d, state, null));
    }

    public override void Send (SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread == _executingThread) {
            WorkItem requestedWorkItem = new WorkItem (d, state, null);
            _workItems.Enqueue (requestedWorkItem);
            WorkItem executedWorkItem = null;
            do {
                executedWorkItem = ExecuteAndReturnNextWorkItem ();
            } while (executedWorkItem != null && executedWorkItem != requestedWorkItem);
        } else {
            using (var reset = new ManualResetEventSlim ()) {
                _workItems.Enqueue (new WorkItem (d, state, reset));
                reset.Wait ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a (everything additional removed) example of my main loop:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var synchronizationContext = new CustomSynchronizationContext ();
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext (synchronizationContext);

        while (true) {
            // Do something else in my loop;

            while (synchronizationContext.HasWorkItems) {
                synchronizationContext.ExecuteNextWorkItem ();
            }
        }
    }
```

It is my first attempt at doing something on that level in the CLR concerning threading, so I wonder whether I have made any mistake in writing it, or done some other kind of mispractice (e.g. wrong class, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need to implement `Dispose` pattern if you have no unmanaged resources to dispose. Unless you get paid per line of code, that is :)
2. You should not dispose objects you did not create (unless you implement a wrapper). In your case, you should not dispose reset event in `WorkItem` class, since you did not create it there. Instead, you should use

   ```
   using(var reset = new ManualResetEventSlim())
   {
       _workItems.Enqueue (new WorkItem (d, state, reset));
       ...
   }
   ```
3. this code:

   ```
   while (true) 
   {
       synchronizationContext.Send(_ => Console.WriteLine("Hello!"), null)

       while (synchronizationContext.HasWorkItems) {
           synchronizationContext.ExecuteWorkItem ();
       }
   }
   ```

   will hang your application. You should either remove resetEvent from `Send` method and simply execute all queued `WorkItem`s there (bad approach) or move this loop:

   ```
       while (synchronizationContext.HasWorkItems) {
           synchronizationContext.ExecuteWorkItem ();
       }
   ```

   to sepatrate thread (better approach). Might look like:

   ```
   public sealed class CustomSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext, IDisposable
   {
        public CustomSynchronizationContext()
        {
            _thread = new Thread(() => 
                  {
                      while(true)
                      {
                          _itemQueuedEvent.WaitOne();
                          if (_disposed) return;
                          ExecuteWorkItem();
                      }
                  });
            _thread.Start();
        }

    ........
   }
   ```

   You will probably encounter some synchronization issues, but nothing that can not be solved.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I completely agree on 1 and 2. However, concerning item 3, I had forgotten to mention that I want all the work items to execute on a specific thread. I believe that the correct solution in that case would be to execute all `WorkItem`s when `Send` is called synchronously from the correct thread.

Comment: @JeanHominal, well, yes, either that, or you can dispatch `Execute` method calls to the thread you need using wpf dispatcher. Or some other dispatcher (there is plenty available on the net), if you dont want a wpf dependency. Depending on what other code this thread executes, this might improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

A sycnhronisation context is still a powerful and meaningful API, since [task schedulers rely on them](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8). However, I have some concerns with your implementation.

#### Exception Management

You have no exception management in place.

- `Post` requires the *synchronization context* to handle the exception.
- `Send` requires the exception to be propagated up to the caller.

As a consequence, any exception short-circuits signaling threads that are awaiting completion of the callback.

> ```
> public void Execute ()
> {
>     _callback (_state); // <- on error
>     if (_reset != null) {
>         _reset.Set ();   // <-- this will not be called
>     }
> }
> ```

---

#### Proposed Solution

Simplify the work item. Extract threading flow from it.

```
        private sealed class WorkItem
        {
            private readonly SendOrPostCallback _callback;
            private readonly object _state;

            public WorkItem(SendOrPostCallback callback, object state)
            {
                if (callback == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");

                _callback = callback;
                _state = state;
            }

            public void Execute()
            {
                _callback(_state);
            }
        }
```

Let `Post` and `Send` have distinct exception management.

```
        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            _workItems.Enqueue(new WorkItem(arg => 
            {
                try
                {
                    d(arg);
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    // TODO handle internally, but don't propagate it up the stack
                }

            }, state));
        }

        public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            if (Thread.CurrentThread == _executingThread)
            {
                // Execute inline
                new WorkItem(d, state).Execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Exception executionException = null;
                using (var signal = new ManualResetEventSlim())
                {
                    _workItems.Enqueue(new WorkItem(arg =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            d(arg);
                        }
                        catch (Exception error)
                        {
                            executionException = error;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            signal.Set();
                        }

                    }, state));

                    signal.Wait();
                }
                if (executionException != null)
                {
                    throw new TargetInvocationException("failure executing the callback", executionException);
                }
            }
        }
```